# NSTimer not reliable when transitioning to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I'm using an NSTimer to play an audio file every x number of seconds. The audio files are in sync with a constantly running process, so the interval of the NSTimer is the shortest it can be (to my knowledge):

```
self.updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.updateTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

My problem occurs during the transition to the background state e.g. when the user clicks the home button. It seems that a latency occurs with the timer, and the "updateTimerFired:" method isn't called as reliably during the transition. This results in the audio files playing out of sync, although they eventually sync back up after the transition is complete. Note that my app incorporates the Audio background mode.

Is there a more reliable tool other than NSTimer to ensure that the latency does not occur when transitioning to the background?

Comment: Did you consider using local notifications instead? I've used that in the passed for a similar problem, and do not remember I had latency problems.. And are you using a background task for this?

Comment: @MCMatan I've tried implementing background tasks but the latency still occurred. I hadn't considered local notifications. I'll look into it and see if they'll work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok, you should check local notification maybe it will suit you well. Also, are you re creating a NSTimer with the delta difference between then for the background task, or are you using the same one?

Comment: @MCMatan I'm only creating one NSTimer instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up replacing the NSTimer with `dispatch_source_create`:

```
self.timerQueue = dispatch_queue_create("updateTimerQueue", nil);
self.updateTimer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, self.timerQueue);
dispatch_source_set_timer(self.updateTimer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (1 * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 50, (1 * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 20);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.updateTimer, ^{
    [self updateTimerFired];
});
dispatch_resume(self.updateTimer);
```

This provides a dedicated queue for the timer to perform on, and is not interrupted by a transition to the background.